# Take input from a file and have each value separated by spaces be put into a variable

Tags: perl, split

First time poster and my first time trying to script in Perl so be gentle with me.

What I need to do is read a log file that contains ip's and port numbers. The contents of the file are:

```
6056 255.255.255.255 6056 255.255.255.255 80
16056 255.255.255.255 16056 255.255.255.255 80
7056 255.255.255.255 7056 255.255.255.255 80
17056 255.255.255.255 17056 255.255.255.255 80
```

The file contains more entries like this.

The first value of every line needs to be extracted and added to a variable `$LocalPort`, the second value of every line assigned to `$LicenseServer`, third value `$RemotePort`, fourth value `$ShServer`, fifth value `$ShServerport`.

At the end of every loop values are will be inserted into `$command` variable and written to a file that can be run as a script to establish a vsh connection. I can read in the file just fine but I am unsure of how to extract each value and assign it to the appropriate value each time it goes threw the loop. I currently have this:

```
open (LOGFILE, $LogPath) || "Unable to open the log file or file does not exist $!";
while (@line =  <LOGFILE>)
{
    $LocalPort=$line[0]; 
    $LicenseServer=$line[1];
    $RemotePort=$line[2];
    $ShServer=$line[3];
    $ShServerpor=$line[4];

    print "$LocalPort\n";
    print "$LicenseServer\n"
    print "$RemotePort\n";
    print "ShServer\n";
    print "ShServerPort\n";
}
```

So far all I can get it to do is spit back the exact file as it reads it in. This is really my first attempt at scripting and I have no training other then what I can gather from lord Google. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get it working! A few more googles and I found a solution.

chomp;

($lport, $lserver, $rport, $sserver, $sport) = split("\ ");

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^\s*$/; #skip empty lines
    my($local_port, $license_server, $remote_port, $sh_server, $sh_server_port) = split;
    print "$local_port\n";
    #....
}
```

use as

```
perl my_script.pl < file_with_data.txt
```

or

```
perl my_script.pl file_with_data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`@line =  <LOGFILE>` reads the entire file into `@line`. What you need is something like this:

```
while (<LOGFILE>) {
   ( $LocalPort, $LicenseServer,
       $RemotePort,$ShServer,$ShServerpor ) = split (/\s/, $_ );
}
```

Comment: Thank you might stackoverflow community. I now have the full script and all of its requirements up and running :) This scripting stuff is kind of fun. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Dan to stackoverflow.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
# ALWAYS declare these two lines
use strict;
use warnings;

my $logPath = '/path/to/logfile';
# use 3 args open and test for failure
open my $fh, '<', $logPath or die "unable to open '$logPath' for reading: $!";

# read one line at a time
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    # delete line separator
    chomp $line;
    # split each line on spaces
    my ($LocalPort, $LicenseServer, $RemotePort, $ShServer, $ShServerpor) = split/\s+/, $line;

    # do the stuff with the variables

}
#close the file and test for failure
close $fh or die "unable to close '$logPath' : $!";
```